# How to set the default printer settings for all remote desktop users in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, printing, printer

I have a Windows 7 machine to which many LAN users access, to use some applications in Remote Desktop. That machine has a printer too. People use this PC also to print.

The problem is that when a person prints, it prints in colors. I'd like to set black and white as the default setting for all users.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error i adapted a solution for Windows server 2008 R2 that worked.

The solution is go to 
`Control panel / System and security / Admin Tools` (translating from Italian so i hope it is good)

Then on the right navigate in the tree to

```
Print management/ Print servers/YOUR_PC/Printers
```

and in the control panel choose the printer
right click on it
choose "Default print settings"
and set the defaults.